# How can I access the cookies on the sequence in Loopback 4?

Tags: v4l2loopback

How can I access the cookies on the sequence in Loopback 4 ?
I need to validate a session that is sent in a cookie,
how can I access its value in loopback 4?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sequence file, you have your request like this:

```
const {request, response} = context;
```

You can then use request.headers.cookie to get your cookie.
This is the simple answer.

But to validate your session, I think it would be better to implement a middleware in your sequence and then do your authentication there. You can get some inspiration from there: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/packages/authentication